# Getting IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm getting the above exception and error on the following code, which is meant to play a selected mp3 file from Isolated Storage:

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{            
     using (var isfs = isf.OpenFile(selected.Path, FileMode.Open))
     {                        
          this.media.SetSource(isfs);              
          isfs.Close();                        
     }                    
     isf.Dispose();
}
```

The error is so vague that I'm not really sure what could be wrong... Any ideas or at least common sources of this error that I could potentially check for?

EDIT: the exception is being thrown at: `using(var isfs = isf.OpenFile(...))`

EDIT 2: The stack trace...

```
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
at Ringify.Phone.PivotContent.RingtoneCollectionPage.MediaIconSelected(Object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I've realized too that the error does NOT occur if I play one song then stop it (there is a play and pause button in the UI), then play another song. It occurs when I play one song, stop it, and attempt to play the same song again.

Comment: Which instruction is triggering the error, isf.OpenFile? If so, make sure that the file exists. You can check by calling `isf.FileExists(selected.Path)` before opening the file

Comment: Yes, it's that line. I did an informal check by writing to console the results of `isf.FileExists(selected.Path)` since I thought maybe that was the case, but it does and putting in a an actual if-statement doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this code would throw an exception with an existing file. Can you show us the value of `selected.Path`?

Comment: selected.Path just returns an appended version of the folder name (ie: music) and file name (ie: song1.mp3) in isolated storage, based on a pre-created folder and a pre-saved file.

So for example: "music/song1.mp3"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem occurs when you play the same music twice, therefore it may be a file sharing problem. You should try to provide the FileShare parameter of the `OpenFile` method:

```
var isfs = isf.OpenFile(selected.Path, FileMode.Open, FileShare.Read)
```

Though I don't understand why it would happen, since you're explicitly closing the file.

**EDIT:** OK, did some digging with Reflector, and I figured it out. The code of MediaElement.SetSource is:

```
public void SetSource(Stream stream)
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
    }
    if (stream.GetType() != typeof(IsolatedStorageFileStream))
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Stream must be of type IsolatedStorageFileStream");
    }
    IsolatedStorageFileStream stream2 = stream as IsolatedStorageFileStream;
    stream2.Flush();
    stream2.Close();
    this.Source = new Uri(stream2.Name, UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

So basically it doesn't use the stream you give, and it even closes it. But it keeps the name of the file, and I guess it re-opens it when you play the music. Therefore, if you try to re-open the same file with exclusive access while the music is playing, it fails because the MediaElement has the file opened. Tricky.

Comment: That worked! Ty so much. :) I didn't think I needed it either since I explicitly close the file... But that fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad it worked, but I'm clueless. I guess that somehow `media.SetSource` prevents the stream from being closed... What is the type of `media`? If you remove the `this.media.SetSource(isfs)` line, without adding the FileShare parameter, do you still have the error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using an [IsolatedStorageFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{            
     using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(selected.Path, FileMode.Open, isf))
     {                        
          this.media.SetSource(isfs);              
     }                    
}
```

Also, note that you do not need to call the `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods as they are taken care of in the using statements.